# Dig returns incorrect DNS record, but only on specific network. What's wrong?

Tags: domain-name-system

I was trying to SSH into my server at https://myrtlelime.com, but I noticed that I couldn't (despite being able to visit it on Chrome).

On my local computer, I get this output when running it:

```
$dig @ns3.he.net myrtlelime.com +short
18.204.152.241
```

This is incorrect, and looking in my DNS records, I can find no mention of this IP address. I get the same result from another Linux system on my local network, as well as in both Windows and Mac.

However, if I run dig on any of my servers, I get:

```sh
$ dig @ns3.he.net myrtlelime.com +short
47.90.8.107
```

**Edit:** I thought that this might be because my DNS host (Hurricane Electric - he.net) was messing something up, so I copied all my zones to Cloudflare. The weird thing is, Cloudflare now also returns the same thing! But once again only on my local network.

```sh
$ dig @piper.ns.cloudflare.com myrtlelime.com +short
18.204.152.241
```

**End edit**

What might be causing this problem? Is my ISP somehow rewriting my DNS records before they arrive?

Comment: Did you ever find out what caused this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are querying the authoritative server directly, caching should not be a factor.

I see two main options:

- `ns3.he.net` is anycast (which I believe is the case) and some anycast node(s) are out of sync. This would only make sense as an explanation if the record had the value `18.204.152.241` at some point, though.
- Your ISP, you, or potentially someone else is intercepting DNS in/from your network and providing different answers.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I thought maybe HE (my DNS host) is messing things up so I copied all the zone information over to Cloudflare (see my edit). Weirdly, I encounter the same thing:  querying it gives the wrong response, but only on my network. I feel some kind of interception must be going on, but I'm mystified as to who and why. I'll keep trying to work around it!

Comment: @phsource It's either your ISP, or some hardware you have installed yourself on your own network.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out - it was due to the Plume (HomePass) WiFi system having a malicious site blocker. Not sure how it got flagged, but I just disabled it for now!

Answer (score 0):

my first thought is DNS caching problem... Whenever the "owner" of the DNS record changes it, it takes some time to propagate the change through the network, because DNS servers cache the last response in order to reduce the network load.

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
p2.myrtlelime.com.      300     IN      A       47.90.8.107
```

300 is the TTL, in seconds - so this is a rather short cache time... but some wrongly implemented dns servers / ISPs cache such entries longer than the TTL. I would flush any DNS cache you have on your PC, and if nothing helps, switch to google's public DNS server...

Answer (score 0):

18.204.152.241 is an AWS EC2 instance (in us-east-1) (checked using https://bgp.he.net/ )

Also for info, the Chrome extension IPvFoo will tell you what IP address a URL resolves in Chrome.

Maybe this helps narrow down the issue for you.